# How to make "Set Feature Image" in WordPress to be required

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am trying to have the "Set Feature Image" options in all posts to be required. As in it wont let the post be published unless the feature image is set in.

I have been trying to use the functions.php file to make this happen but I am not sure how to begin with it. Can any of you assist? Thanks so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Require authors to set featured image for post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410402/require-authors-to-set-featured-image-for-post) and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74464/make-featured-image-required

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/19822056/1427161